# select all from two joined table with common column name

Tags: sql-server

I two tables with different column names except one column `id`.

Im using below code to join them and also diferentiate the `id` column from each other.

```
SELECT a.id as table_id, * 
FROM [CFG].[pipeline_tables] a
LEFT JOIN [CFG].[pipeline_columns] on a.[id]=[pipeline_columns].[pipeline_tables_id]
```

but `id` column from `pipeline_tables` is picked two times ( original name `id` and new name `table_id`) and also plus the `id` columns from `pipeline_columns`.

Desired out put should be two `Id` columns with the changed names as `table_id` and `column_id`

Comment: Because that's what you asked for; `a.id as table_id, <All columns from All tables>`, `*` means return **every column**. If you don't want to list the `id` of `a` (which is a poor alias for a table named `pipeline_tables`; see [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)) a second time, then explicitly list the columns you want.

Comment: don't use *, instead specify every column manually